# Using declarative RxJS, is there a way to pass Observable data to child component from parent component?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I'm using declarative RxJS to return a response object from my back-end service. I am able to grab the data in my `bay-page.ts` file and display it in my html. However, I want the data to be displayed in my `results-page.ts` file. I grab the user inputs using Subjects and pass them in a method in my `bay-page.ts` file, that will then fire off the HTTP request.

**But, how do I grab those results and display them in my `results-page.html` file?**

`bay-service.ts` file:

```
private bayStartSelectedSubject = new Subject<number>();
  bayStartSelectedAction$ = this.bayStartSelectedSubject.asObservable();

  private bayEndSelectedSubject = new Subject<number>();
  bayEndSelectedAction$ = this.bayEndSelectedSubject.asObservable();


  selectedBayChanged(selectedBayStartNumber: number, selectedBayEndNumber?: number): void {
    this.bayStartSelectedSubject.next(selectedBayStartNumber);
    this.bayEndSelectedSubject.next(selectedBayEndNumber);
  }

  grabHuResponsePOST$ = combineLatest([
    this.bayStartSelectedAction$,
    this.bayEndSelectedAction$
  ])
    .pipe(
      switchMap(([bayStart, bayEnd]) => {
        if (bayEnd == null || bayEnd <= 0) {
          bayEnd = bayStart;
        }
        let huRequest: HuRequest = {
          "centerId": "COS",
          "beginBayId": bayStart,
          "endBayId": bayEnd
        }
        const headers = new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        });
        let options = {
          headers: headers
        }
        // this.invalidBay.next(true);
        return this.httpClient.post<HuResponse>(this.HandlingUnitResponseUrl, huRequest, options);
      }),
      tap(showDataPlease => console.log('Bays: ', JSON.stringify(showDataPlease))),
    );
```

`bay-page.ts` file:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.bayForm = new FormGroup({
      'bayStart': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
      'bayEnd': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required])
    });
    this.bayService.invalidBay$.subscribe(
      value => {
        console.log(value);
        this.invalidBay = value;
      }
    );
    this.bayService.grabHuResponsePOST$.subscribe(p => {

    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.bayService.selectedBayChanged(this.bayForm.get('bayStart').value, this.bayForm.get('bayEnd').value);
    this.navCtrl.navigateForward([`/results/`]);
  }
```

`results-page.ts` file:

```
bayOrBays$ = this.bayService.grabHuResponsePOST$
    .pipe(
      map(response => response.bays),
      catchError(err => {
        this.errorMessageSubject.next(err);
        return EMPTY;
      }),
      tap(showDataPlease => console.log('Bays: ', JSON.stringify(showDataPlease)))
    );
```

`results-page.html` file:

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let bay of bayOrBays$ | async; index as i"
                    class="ion-no-margin">
            <ion-card-header>
              <ion-card-title>Bay {{ bay.bayCode }}</ion-card-title>
              <ion-card-subtitle>{{ bay.shipments.length }} Shipments</ion-card-subtitle>
            </ion-card-header>
          </ion-card>
```

I am obviously missing something with a subscription because this doesn't work in my `results-page.ts` file, but it DOES work, if I put it in my `bay-page.ts` file.

Comment: What do you mean by “it doesn’t work”? Is it that nothing is emitted?

Comment: In that no data will be displayed in my `results-page.ts`. However, If I use the same bayorBays$ in my `bay-page.ts` file, and do the html stuff, the data will be displayed. So I'm losing the data somehow in my `results-page.ts` file.

Comment: Is this the same issue as your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66631915/async-pipe-and-ngfor-are-not-displaying-items-from-http-request) ?  If so, I suggest closing one of them out.

Comment: does your `results-page` call `selectedBayChanged()` on your service?  It looks like that is what makes the `grabHuResponsePOST ` observable emit.

Comment: Yes, they are similar, and I will close the other one. My `results-page.ts` does not call `selectedBayChanged()` because it is the results screen. I had this working with an in-memory db but for some reason now it doesn't work. So the `bay-page.ts` is the first page where the user inputs a bayStart and bayEnd and then that will make the `grabHuResponsePOST` emit. And in my `results-page.ts` file, I try to access that data but to no avail I guess.

Comment: I see! So the results page is subscribing AFTER the observable emits. Is this correct?

Comment: Well, I believe that's the case. But I have literally the exact same code except using an in-memory db on a different project, and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, late subscribers will not receive previously emitted values.  You can use the [`shareReplay`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/multicasting/sharereplay) operator to emit prior values to new subscribers upon subscription:

```js
grabHuResponsePOST$ = combineLatest([
    this.bayStartSelectedAction$,
    this.bayEndSelectedAction$
  ])
    .pipe(
      switchMap(([bayStart, bayEnd]) => {
        if (bayEnd == null || bayEnd <= 0) {
          bayEnd = bayStart;
        }
        let huRequest: HuRequest = {
          "centerId": "COS",
          "beginBayId": bayStart,
          "endBayId": bayEnd
        }
        const headers = new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        });
        let options = {
          headers: headers
        }
        // this.invalidBay.next(true);
        return this.httpClient.post<HuResponse>(this.HandlingUnitResponseUrl, huRequest, options);
      }),
      tap(showDataPlease => console.log('Bays: ', JSON.stringify(showDataPlease))),
      shareReplay(1) // <-----
    );
```

Comment: I will try this, but how am I able to get the data shown on the `results-page.html` screen with this exact same code (besides using an in-memory db) on a different project? This is what's so confusing to me. I will give your suggestion a shot.

Comment: Yep, that works! But now I'm even more confused haha. I appreciate the help though!